# Is the boundary of this set compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ a subspace of $X$ and $A\subseteq Y $ such that $\partial(A)$ is compact in $X$. Is $\partial(A)$ compact in $Y$?

Comment: Be careful; does $\partial(A)$ mean the boundary of $A$ in the topology of $X$, or in the subspace topology of $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because compactness is an inner property of the set

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Dimitris's answer:

If $S$ is a subset of a space $X$, then $S$ is "compact in $X$" if and only if $S$ is a compact space when considered under the subspace topology. That is, the compactness of $S$ does not depend on its relationship to the rest of $X$. That is why we normally *don't* say "$A$ is compact in $B$" but rather just "$A$ is compact".